# Finding tangent line to curve $x^y-y^x+1=0$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

As the title said, I need to find tangent to the curve  $x^y-y^x+1=0$, in the point $T(1,2)$ but I don't know how to fond derivative of this implicit function. Of course, I think I could use $\ln$ but "+1" is the problematic part. What can I do?

Comment: It is "0" but I think I shouldn't just "eliminate" it? It can effect the derivative of implicite function? For example, in $xy-a=0$ derivative is $dy/dx=\frac{-a}{x^2}$

Comment: No. If you had $xy-a=0$, with $a$ a constant, the differentiating would give $x\frac{dy}{dx}+y=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite as :
$$
e^{y\ln(x)}-e^{x\ln(y)}+1=0
$$
Now differentiate with respect to $x$:
$$
e^{y\ln(x)}\frac{d}{dx}\left[ y\ln(x) \right]-e^{x\ln(y)}\frac{d}{dx}\left[ x\ln(y) \right]=0
$$
then:
$$
e^{y\ln(x)} \left[ \ln(x)\frac{dy}{dx}+ \frac{y}{x}\right]-e^{x\ln(y)}\left[ \ln(y)+\frac{x}{y}\frac{dy}{dx} \right]=0
$$
or
$$
x^y \left[ \ln(x)\frac{dy}{dx}+ \frac{y}{x}\right]-y^x\left[ \ln(y)+\frac{x}{y}\frac{dy}{dx} \right]=0
$$
Now rearrange and plug in $x=1$ and $y=2$ to find the slope of the tangent at $(1,2)$, and then use that to find the equation of the tangent.

Answer (score 1):

Use implicit differentiation. $D/dx(x^y)+D/dy(x^y)(dy/dx)-D/dx(y^x)-D/dy(y^x)(dy/dx)=0$. The 1 goes away because D(1)=0 regardless what variable you derivative with respect to. Then, take the derivatives and solve for dy/dx. Once you have dy/dx on one side, plug in the point T to the other side to get the slope.